# No version set for command go

Tags: go, ubuntu

I attempted to check the version of my `go` executable with `go version` on an Ubuntu machine, however I got the following error:

```
No version set for command go
Consider adding one of the following versions in your config file at 
golang 1.16.8
golang 1.17.1
```

How do I resolve this? I have no prior experience with config file, I searched on google but I found nothing which could solve this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That seems to be an error message from [`asdf-vm/asdf`](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf), a tool which manages multiple runtime versions with a single CLI tool, extendable via plugins.
You can see that error message in [`asdf-vm/asdf` issue 838](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf/issues/838).

The [config file](https://asdf-vm.com/manage/configuration.html) should be in `$HOME/.tool-versions`

To resolve this, as in [this example](https://golangexample.com/setting-up-golang-on-my-computer/):

```
asdf plugin add go
asdf install go latest
```